# unable to return List of dictionary in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am new in WCF.
I am trying to return list of dictionary in wcf.

Here is my code.

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
 {
   public List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetData(string query)
    {
          List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
          ...
          ...
          return rows;
    }

 }

public interface IService1
{
    [WebGet()]
    [OperationContract]
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetData();
}
```

If I return return string it will work properly I want to return list like this.

Comment: no I am not get any error on browser side but not get any result.

Comment: Do not return object on your operation contract. Instead, define an Interface and then use the ServiceKnownType attribute to define the set of implementations which can be exposed over the service boundary.

Comment: @TomRedfern if possible please give me example of this .

Answer (score 1):

You have to create class and set attribute `KnownType`.

```
 [DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<Dictionary<string, object>>))]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public IDictionary<String, Object> Inputs { get; set; }
}
```

Now instead `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` use `List<Foo>`
You can do like this sample.

**IService**

```
        [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
   UriTemplate = "GetData")]
    List<Foo> GetData();
```

**Service**

```
    public List<Foo> GetData()
    {
        List<Foo> rows = new List<Foo>();
        var x = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        x.Add("sss","sss");
        x.Add("zzz", "zzz");
        x.Add("aaa", "aaa");
        var z = new Foo();
       z.Inputs = x;

        rows.Add(z);
        rows.Add(z);
        return rows;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: its not working its show me the WCf not support this type.

Comment: I tested it and it working. Btw you see image with result. Which type not supported in your opinion?